# php same result adding different number of vars

Tags: php

Can anybody explain why these 2 produce the same result?

```
$a = 1;
$c = $a + $a++;
var_dump($c);//int(3)
```

and

```
$a = 1;
$c = $a + $a + $a++;
var_dump($c);//int(3)
```

Tested in PHP 7.1. Reviewed Opcode dumps for both cases but still cant get the point. If we add more $a vars to the expression, it produces the expected result.

Comment: I could point that is similary to this `var_dump((int)((0.1 + 0.7) * 10));//int(7)` ([a float precision problem](http://titanic.fauser.edu/php/language.types.float.php.htm#warn.float-precision)) . But I really don't know.

Comment: See also https://3v4l.org/3bWI0

Comment: This is explained here: https://gist.github.com/nikic/6699370 There's probably also one or ten duplicates on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [PHP: Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions
>   are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. **PHP does not
>   (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is
>   evaluated** and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should
>   be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or
>   depending on the surrounding code.
>
> **Example #2 Undefined order of evaluation**
>
> ```
> $a = 1;
> echo $a + $a++; // may print either 2 or 3
>
> $i = 1;
> $array[$i] = $i++; // may set either index 1 or 2
> ```

So in your first example, PHP is obviously returning `1` for `$a++` then incrementing it to `2` and then adding the new `$a`, which is `2`.

In your second example, PHP is returning `1` for `$a` then adding `$a` then adding `$a` and then incrementing it to `2`.

As can be seen here: https://3v4l.org/kvrTr:

**PHP 5.1.0 - 7.1.0**

```
int(3)
int(3)
```

**PHP 4.3.0 - 5.0.5**

```
int(2)
int(3)
```

Comment: is this a bug or feature? it does happens in javascript too `var a = 1;
var c = a + a++;
console.log(c);

var a = 1;
var c = a + a + a++;
console.log(c);`